# No details for authentication in Authlogic & Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

After following the guide to add Facebook Connect to an Authlogic-enabled Rails app (see http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect), I get the following error when I click on the Facebook's "Connect" button:

You did not provide any details for authentication.

It seems that UserSession.create(params[:user_session]) is trying to authenticate with the standard user and password, but the only params available are the authenticity token.

What additional configuration am I missing?

UPDATE: I've made some discoveries. First, the cookie is named fbsetting_{api_key}, instead of fbs_{api_key} (which is what Facebooker expects), for some reason related to API version. Also, the contents of the cookie don't seem to be what Facebooker expects. I don't know if there's a way to select a specific Facebook API version to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Having similar issues here. Lots of the options on http://facebooker.pjkh.com/fb-init-options/app_settings_demo_ifuser work nicely for me, but authlogic facebooker out of the box does not work.
UPDATE: It was my app settings on facebook itself, meant authentication was never being setn back to my site... removing site domain sorted it.

Comment: Is "site domain" under the "web site" tab and "core settings" section of the application settings in facebook?